Virtualbox won't boot a Windows partition in a dual boot system: "failed to load Boot0001 UEFI VBOX HARDDISK: Not found"
So I have a system with one hard drive with three partitions: Ubuntu 23.10, Windows 11 and a shared exFat partition for data.
The dual boot via grub works fine, but I want to be able to boot into the Windows partition via Virtualbox occasionally. However when I try booting the VM it fails with the following message:

I have created the vdisk with the following command:
sudo vboxmanage createmedium disk --filename Windows.vmdk --format=VMDK --variant rawdisk --property RawDrive=/dev/sda3

And then attached it to the VM:

Notice the Ubuntu live CD: I used that to boot the VM into a live environment, from which I mounted the Windows partition, which worked fine.
What could be going wrong?

@John Are you sure? I can find plenty of references to this kind of setup across the internet, e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/g8ew12/can_i_use_my_other_dualboot_partition_as_a_vm/

You created a virtual HDD out of a single partition, the NTFS partition with Windows. That is not bootable on its own, especially not on an UEFI system – the firmware doesn't understand NTFS, and the actual bootloader lives on a completely different partition (the FAT32-formatted EFI System Partition, which is most likely sda1). Your virtual HDD must include both partitions, together with an actual GPT partition table referencing them.
In short, you'll need to create a virtual HDD out of the entire disk.
